# Directing not empty output into a file

Tags: command-line, redirect, tee

I want to save only non-empty output of find command into a file. If there is no output file should not be created.

```
$ ls folder
aa
$ find . -name 'bb' | tee file
$ cat file
$ ls folder
aa file
```

How to do it?

Comment: I would probably wrap the find function in `if` statement, testing e.g. that `wc -l` of the result is higher then zero, but i would neet to think about the syntax (and google a bit) more hard than i have time now..

Comment: Thanks for idea. I think dirty way is to wc -l file and if it is 0, than $ rm file.   IT goes like this:   num=`wc -l file | grep -o [0-9]`  Then:                                                            if [ $num -eq 0 ]; then rm tostik; fi

Answer (score 5):

The utility [`ifne`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ifne) from package [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) should accomplish what you want:

```
$ find . -name 'bb' | ifne tee file
```

From the man page:

> **Description**
>
> **ifne** runs the following command if and only if the standard input is not empty.

Comment: Nice - learn something every day ;)

Comment: Tnx, but I want something without ifne, since I cannot add from packages

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-exec` option, which will only run if files are found:

```
find . -name 'bb' -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" | tee -a file' sh {} +
```

Explanation:

- `printf "%s\n" "$@"` Print each argument with a trailing newline.
- `sh` The second argument to `sh -c` gets assigned to `$0`.
- `{} +` As `-exec` arguments, these stand for "all selected files". `sh -c` assigns these to `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: `tee -a` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @muru Would it? What if OP wants to specifically overwrite the file?

Comment: Just for the rare case where the paths are long enough for `sh` to be run twice (or more)

Comment: @muru Ah, I hadn't thought of that.